# What is the best way to handle modal popups on a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Would the proper way to add them be

A) hiding the div contents on the page and showing it when bound to a click

OR

B) just fetching the data asynchronously and loading it into an empty div that's hidden on the page?

Per the responses below... Use cases? Here:

1) Logging in

2) Showing a "share modal box w/ social sharing stuff"

3) Submission of data

Comment: so many words, so little punctuation.

Comment: Give your specific use case. There are many reasons to show a modal popup and solutions depend on why you are doing it.

Comment: Well, the answer obviously depends on your specifics, which you've so far neglected to share... Also, have you seen [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/when-should-you-use-a-modal-dialog-box)?

Comment: @Cameron No, but great link. I didn't even know we had a UX SE. Gracias.

Comment: Ah! A login box. Be sure to allow users with Javascript turned off to still have a means of logging in. Also make sure that the credentials are always secured (HTTPS) going over the wire.

Comment: @Cameron Yeah, I'll probably end up attaching an href to the anchor text along with binding it to the popup event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like to create them on-the-fly.

```
dialog = $("<div></div>");
dialog.html(content);
dialog.dialog({modal:true});
```

This is using jQuery UI's dialog feature, but just wanted to example creating on the fly.

Comment: Nice. Creating them on the fly seems to be the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way to go far would be to use the [FancyBox Plugin](http://fancybox.net/)

All the examples you need have a [DEMO](http://fancybox.net/home) here

Comment: Link is broken, but I'd rather just build it myself and as it'd be leaner and I can add additional features to it as I see fit.

Comment: great, but the link isn't broken, demos are at the bottom. as a learner you shouldn't rely on plugins. I just gave a  short cut fix

Comment: Odd. It didn't load for me earlier. I'm well aware of FancyBox and I agree that you shouldn't rely on plugins as a learner. But maybe you misread the word I used which was "leaner". E.g. less bloat.

Comment: yup, completely understood, i read it as learner, I am not a good reader.